# Export yahoo calendar

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, yahoo, yahoo-api

I want to export Yahoo calendar (the events) via c#. For google calendar there are a lot of examples and code in the web and I succeed to export google events, but I didn't find almost nothing about exporting yahoo calendar. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes documentation does seem to be rather surprisingly scarce, Here is some information I found [Here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/calendar/yahoocalendar/misc/misc-01.html)

> API access to Yahoo! Calendar can be obtained through our CalDAV
>   interface. CalDAV is a calendar synchronization protocol, which simply
>   means that a handful of calendars such as Apple iCal and Mozilla
>   Lightning/Sunbird use it to make their data interchangeable across
>   other calendars, including Yahoo! Calendar.
>
> The Yahoo! Calendar CalDAV server URL is:
>   https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com
>
> The specification for CalDAV can be found at:
>   http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4791.txt?number=4791

There is also this .Net iCal class library that might help you http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/